# How to disable Microsoft EDGE suggestions when typing a '/' on a TextFormField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, textformfield

In my chat app, the '/' symbol is used for quick responses. But when I open it on Web (Microsoft EDGE) and try to type the '/' symbol, EDGE shows filling suggestions. I wanna know if there's a way of turning that off inside the Flutter app.